# Error while trying to update p2 site with Buckminster

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, target-platform, buckminster

I am really new in buckminster.
   I have just downloaded from our repository an Eclipse RCP project that needs a plugin update (placed in its Target Platform). We are currently using a remote target platform.

I have downloaded the remote target platform configuring its path in the targetplatform.source project, then I did the update and reload it checking the plugin's version. I have changed the version number in feature.xml on my targetplatform.feature project (that contains the buckminster.properties file).

The problem comes when I right-click on the targetplatform.feature project, select Buckminster > Invoke action... > site.p2. This just rise an error and the console shows the Buckminster log with the same error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: case variants of key: awt.toolkit: case variants of key: awt.toolkit
```

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I finally had to stop using a remote target platform as I could not solve the Buckminster problem. The workaround described below covered my plugin update needs.

In order to have a control version system, the plugin update problem can be managed by having a repository manager (for example Nexus). Then you can simply upload a zip of your target platform with the updated plugins. Nevertheless, this forces the configuration to set the target platfom as local and therefore you need to download and unzip it previously.